# how to take cmd output error message as an input to a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

i have a oracle sqldeveloper file.

when i run it by using a batch file, if it encounter an error, the cmd will surely display the error.

what i want is, is it possible to take the cmd error as an input to trigger out my custom made error message??

if in cmd displaying any error for example:

```
Parameter not found
```

my custom-made error message in batch file will triggered out this error message in the cmd:

```
You Got An Error!
```

any help and suggestions are appreciated..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is: if the cmd does NOT display an error, your custom made error message routine will hang forever?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am thinking that when my code is a success, the CMD will automatically exit. This is easy by using Exit command. But if there is error in my code, it will triggered my custom made message..

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output (both stdout and stderr) to a text file (or to `nul` if you don't care about the output), and check the value of `%ERRORLEVEL% after your script has been executed. If it is not 0, then display your own error message.

To redirect both stdout and stderr:

`command parameters 1>>c:\log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: thanks for the respond, but i would like to find a solution which is not depending on the errorlevel as my errorlevel will always return 0 although there are errors in my code..

if im not mistaken, the errorlevel will only check the batch-file, not the code..correct me if im wrong..

thanks in advance

Comment: If you check the value of `%ERRORLEVEL%` after a specific command is executed in your batch file, you will get the error code returned by that command (the SQL command in your case). However, it is possible that the SQL command you use always returns 0. If this is the case, then my solution won't work correctly. @dbenham has posted a potential fix to your problem, maybe you should investigate that path?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using SQL*Plus instead of SQL Developer. You can add WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE to the top of the script (or EXIT SQL.SQLCODE if you are interested in the specific error code). Then the calling batch file will receive the error code in %ERRORLEVEL% and you can take action appropriately. There is also WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE if your SQL script interfaces with the OS with the potential of failure there.

I don't think SQL*Plus uses stderr, so I don't think you need to worry about redirecting 2>&1.